# Can we insert element at a fixed point in LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections

Can we insert Elements at a fixed point in LinkedHashSet. I know that we cant insert elements at a fixed point in HashSet since HashSet doesn't maintain ***Insertion Order***. But Even though LinkedHashSet maintains Insertion Order I couldn't figure out why the following code is throwing error:

```
import java.util.*;  
class Main{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
LinkedHashSet<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<String>();  
       set.add("Two");    
       set.add("Three");   
       set.add("Four");  
       set.set(1,"Five");  
       Iterator<String> i=set.iterator();  
       while(i.hasNext())  
       {  
       System.out.println(i.next());  
       }  
 }  
 }
```

Error:

```
Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
       set.set(1,"Five");  
          ^
symbol:   method set(int,String)
location: variable set of type LinkedHashSet<String>
1 error
```

Comment: It might be worth checking out [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and see what methods are there in `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: If you actually care about the order of elements, specifically *changing* the order of the elements, you're much better off using a `List` than a `Set`.

Comment: The reason why you get an error is precisely stated in the error itself. There is no method set(int,String).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the method `.set` on a `LinkedHashSet`. I think in this case you need an `ArrayList`, like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();  
       list.add("Two");    
       list.add("Three");   
       list.add("Four");  
       list.set(1, "Five");  
       Iterator<String> i = list.iterator();  
       while(i.hasNext())  
       {  
       System.out.println(i.next());  
       }  
 }
```

Note that:

- `ArrayList`s start at 0
- Method `.set` replaces the element that was previously in that position, while `.add` adds a new element there